# $_SESSION variable not passing and no clue why? it sets then doesn't pass

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a login script coded in php and mysqli. upon submission and successful authentication it redirects to success.php to write sessions. my success page looks like this.

```
<?php  
 /**
     * Set cookies here if/as needed.
     * Set session data as needed. DO NOT store user's password in
     * cookies or sessions!
     * Redirect the user if/as required.
     */

     $id = $_GET['id'];

    $_SESSION['partner_id']       = $id;
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = TRUE;

    if (isset($_SESSION['partner_id'])) {
    echo("<script>
    <!--
    location.replace(index.php);
    -->
    </script>");

    }

    else {
        print "Session partner id not set";
    }

?>
```

This page effectively redirects to my index.php page. However my index php does not recognize the session variable.

```
    <?php
 session_start();
 // rest of code
print "ths is the session var".$_SESSION['partner_id'];
    ?>
```

that is at the top of the page before the doctype declaration.

on the page i also have

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['partner_id'])) {
        print "This is the session id variable".$_SESSION['partner_id']; 
        }

        else {
        print "Session not set";
        }

        ?>
```

The top check prints blank and the bottom one prints session not set....

I am confused...

Comment: `session_start();` must be inside **all** files using sessions; if set or not.

Comment: it is......i have that in my post. second box of code. thanks though

Comment: Do this instead `print "This is the session id variable".$id;` since you're doing `$_SESSION['partner_id'] = $id;`

Comment: This is the wrong way to store sessions. create an object or if you don't know how, atleast array with all the info you need(no sensative info please) and store it a single session. that way you can come back later and access your info like `$user = $_SESSION['user'];` then `$user->username;` or `$user->id`

Comment: @KyleK i'm only suggesting he creates an object to house his information then stores it all to a single session, instead of using multiple sessions for each variable his script needs.

Comment: Isn't the second box of code a completely separate file, index.php? Whereas your success.php file is a unique file missing `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Ok, I tested your code. Make sure that your GET isn't empty, from where you're pulling this from.

Comment: The $id variable is passed from the login page when it authenticates....that is the value for the session id.

Comment: Weird for some reason it is working now an hour later.....havent really changed anything.....tried the session start in the success.php file and didnt work and when i removed it it works...

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need session_start() on all pages using $_SESSION

```
  <?php  
 /**
 * Set cookies here if/as needed.
 * Set session data as needed. DO NOT store user's password in
 * cookies or sessions!
 * Redirect the user if/as required.
 */
 session_start();

 $id = $_GET['id'];

$_SESSION['partner_id']       = $id;
$_SESSION['authenticated'] = TRUE;
```

Also...are you sure that $_GET['id'] has a value in it?

And....is your form using **POST** or **GET**?

Ive made that silly mistake before , where form was using POST and I was retrieving variable with GET and getting frustrated.  Just a possibility

Comment: The OP is using it in all pages. [`See comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482937/session-variable-not-passing-and-no-clue-why-it-sets-then-doesnt-pass#comment37896774_24482937)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually I think the OP misunderstood your first comment on the question and that your initial diagnosis was on the mark.

Comment: @faintsignal Actually, both `print "This is the session id variable".$_SESSION['partner_id'];` and `print "This is the session id variable".$id;` in my test proved conclusive. Using/replacing `$id = $_GET['id'];` with `$id = "FRED";` printed "This is the session id variable FRED". So at this point, am certain that the OP's GET is failing.

Comment: [`For crying outloud, read this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482937/session-variable-not-passing-and-no-clue-why-it-sets-then-doesnt-pass#comment37896973_24482937) @faintsignal

Comment: indeed i had misunderstood. success.php was missing the session_start(). however it seems to work without it as well. perhaps my server is not syncing or my browser is cacheing the pages?

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was posted after I made my comment. Anyway, in hindsight I would have waited a bit longer before commenting and let things sort themselves out.

Comment: @user3404390 Again, and as per [`my original comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482937/session-variable-not-passing-and-no-clue-why-it-sets-then-doesnt-pass#comment37896754_24482937) `session_start();` *"must be inside all files using sessions; if set or not."*

Answer (score 0):

Use session_start(); inside all page before using $_SESSION variable in PHP. session_start(); function use to initialize session process.

your success.php should be.

```
<?php  
/**
 * Set cookies here if/as needed.
 * Set session data as needed. DO NOT store user's password in
 * cookies or sessions!
 * Redirect the user if/as required.
 */

 session_start();

 $id = $_GET['id'];

$_SESSION['partner_id']       = $id;
$_SESSION['authenticated'] = TRUE;

if (isset($_SESSION['partner_id'])) {
echo("<script>
<!--
location.replace(index.php);
-->
</script>");

}

else {
    print "Session partner id not set";
}

?>
```

Comment: indeed. i misunderstood freds comment

Answer (score 0):

The initial file didn't contain session_start() as pointed out. however it works without it for some reason now.

I am thinking a cache or server delay issue also

Comment: thats unlikely, but atleast you're showing the critical thinking skill.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answers, If you don't want to write session_start() on starting of each and every page, You can simply skip it by setting the `session.auto_start = 1` in your php.ini file , which starts the session automatically on request page.
[Refer to PHP Session Configuration Documentation.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)